# Idea for this view the list item horizontally in asp.net page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, list, gridview

i need to display the list one by one in the same line.
It mean instead of binding the value in the row i need bind it in new column first row value. Is that any control available to view the item horizontally .

i have my data in data table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly but I think what you want to use is a repeater.  This way you can use whatever markup you want in the itemtemplate to determine what the layout of your data is when it is displayed to the user.  You could do something as simple as <%#Eval("WhatEver")%>  and you would get horizontally repeating values of the WhatEver column.